# Wrong RVM location in PATH with new user on macOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, macos-sierra

I had a working RVM installation on my macOS machine. After the latest upgrade to Sierra I started to see this error whenever I try to run RVM:

```
cat: /Users/flast/.rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/flast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin' is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for 'PATH=...' entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles'.
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p195'.
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
-bash: /Users/flast/.rvm/scripts/base: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/flast/.rvm/scripts/help: No such file or directory
```

There is no such file or directory as user "flast" hasn't existed for a while and it is now "first.last". But in my $PATH it is still calling for "flast"

Here is what is in my PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
/Users/flast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin
/Users/flast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin
/Users/flast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin
/Users/flast/.rvm/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/X11/bin
/usr/local/share/dotnet
/usr/local/git/bin
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
/Users/first.last/.rvm/bin
```

I don't know how to remove the old entries from my PATH permanently, and even when I manually reset my PATH for the current session I still get the above error when I run RVM even when the old user path is not present in the PATH file.

Here is ~/.bashrc

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

here is ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
[[ -s "/Users/first.last/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/first.last/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

What am I doing wrong here? What needs to be done so that RVM knows where to look?

Comment: Also check `~/.profile`

Comment: There is no file at ~/.profile

Comment: Obviously _something_ is setting the path to `flast`. ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile are the likely candidates. What shell are you using? What do `rvm info` and `gem env` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the path was being set by RVM in /Users/first.last/.rvm/environments

The first line in each of the environment files is

```
export PATH; PATH="/Users/flast/.rvm" ...yada yada
```

Changed that and I still get the PATH warning, but RVM and all the gems contained within work as expected.